# ASP.NET URL Rewriting

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting, url-routing

How do I rewrite a URL in ASP.NET?

I would like users to be able to go to

```
http://www.website.com/users/smith
```

instead of

```
http://www.website.com/?user=smith
```

Comment: Scott Guthrie covers how to do this natively in .Net pretty extensively [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx). I've used the httpmodule approach and it works well. It's basically what ManagedFusion is doing for you.

Comment: For step by step explanation follow the below link: http://challadotnetfaq.blogspot.com/2011/08/url-rewritting-in-aspnet.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try the Managed Fusion Url Rewriter and Reverse Proxy:

http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com

The rule for rewriting this would be:

```
# clean up old rules and forward to new URL
RewriteRule ^/?user=(.*)  /users/$1 [NC,R=301]

# rewrite the rule internally
RewriteRule ^/users/(.*)  /?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: A suggestion:  I would adjust the first RewriteRule to look like ^/?users=(\w*) so that http://www.website.com/?users=smith&day=monday doesn't produce http://www.website.com/users/smith&day=monday

Comment: That is a good idea and totally supported in this .NET version.  The original intent was to make my example compatible with mod_rewrite which doesn't support that syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft now ships an official URL Rewriting Module for IIS: http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

It supports most types of rewriting including setting server variables and wildcards.

It also will exist on all Azure web instances out of the box.

Comment: This looks interesting. Do you know if it will work on IIS6 and at what level in the network stack it sits?

Comment: This is a IIS7 and up solution only (its a module http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/121/iis-7-modules-overview/), for IIS6 you will need www.isapirewrite.com or www.urlrewriter.net, isapi rewrite seems like a stable commercial product for iis6

Answer (score 4):

I have used an httpmodule for url rewriting from [www.urlrewriting.net](http://www.urlrewriting.net/) with great success (albeit I believe a much earlier, simpler version)

If you have very few actual rewriting rules then url mappings built in to .NET 2.0 are probably an easier option, there are a few write ups of these on the web, the [4guysfromrolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513223749/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011007-1.aspx) one seems fairly exhaustive but as you can see they don't support regular expression mappings are are as such rendered fairly useless in a dynamic environment (assuming "smith" in your example is not a special case then these would be of no use)