# Can I do this with ASP.NET Routing?

Tags: asp.net, routes

I want to accept a url like this one "www.mysite.com/1-2,3" and turn it one like this "www.mysite.com/page.aspx?a=1&b=2&c=3". Basically I want to know if it's possible to lose .aspx portion, using routing?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915771/asp-net-url-rewriting-vs-routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it's possible.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx