# Dynamic URL Rewriting in ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I am looking to dynamically rewrite urls in asp.net C#.
I want to read the page name from the database and process the request.

For example
PAGENAME: Home
.NETPAGE: Default.aspx?page=1

I think it is possible, can someone point me to right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this question: [ASP.NET - Url Rewriting vs. Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915771/asp-net-url-rewriting-vs-routing)