# ASP.NET Routing or URL Rewriting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing

I'm currently using URL Rewriting, but I recently stumbled upon [this link on Rerouting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#setting_default_values_for_url_parameters), and it looks like it's quite simple yet powerful, and easier to implement than URL Rewriting, a "downside" probably is that configurations are not sitting on a web.config file but rather on the code itself, but I was wondering about the differences, and advantages of using one over the other.

Having read some resources about routing, I can see the differences, and now I reformulate my question:

Is it worth it to move from URL Rewriting to Routing?
Are there any IIS-specific configurations that should be made?
Is it recommended to use it on a ASP.NET WebForms Application, or is it oriented to other kind of projects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET - Url Rewriting vs. Routing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915771/asp-net-url-rewriting-vs-routing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO URL Rewriting has been a workaround in many cases. Rerouting is one of the concepts that supersede URL Rewriting in that cases. In Short: If Rerouting works in your case, you should use it.