# url rewrite for aspx page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have a page, called `foo.aspx` and i d like to rewrite the url as `bar.something`

How to do this? How does url rewrite happens in asp.net

Should i create a generic handler?

or should i get some url rewrite modules and add to app?

Comment: Wtheck? haha. Wrong usage of foo and bar imo?
BTW Aspx is a type.

Comment: Younes, it's a legit question, he's looking for info on URL Rewriting. ASPX isn't necessarily a 'type', it's a file extension and many people would agree that it has no business in the end of a URL, but, for example, using IIS7's rewrite rules I could make it so that a page with *.aspx at the end is served by a .svc or .asmx or .asp file (why I would want to do so is beyond me).

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by configuring IIS, and will require IIS7, look here for configuration help:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

Comment: What @marr75 is (correctly) trying to say is that you need to configure this in IIS. It's got nothing (or maybe not much) to do with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, you also have the new Routing option with ASP.NET 4.0:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90112/iis-url-rewriting-vs-url-routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

You should also check this SO response:

[IIS URL Rewriting vs URL Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90112/iis-url-rewriting-vs-url-routing)

Some basic info on the differences between URL Re-Writing and Routing:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/