# any technique to rewrite URL in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

how to remove .aspx page name and extension and rewrite URL in asp.net
Give any suggestion

Comment: possible duplicate of [url rewrite for aspx page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789312/url-rewrite-for-aspx-page)

Comment: This question shows no research effort. Google for url `rewrite asp.net site:stackoverflow.com` and see articles such as http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Comment: Yes!! i agree with you @TimMedora :). people just wants making points on stackoverflow..

Answer (score 3):

If you are using IIS7+, have a look at this guide.

http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

Comment: +1 IIS 7 URL rewrite module is pretty good for url rewriting in asp.net.
I personally use it.

Answer (score 1):

Use can Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.dll for urlrewriting in .Net. You can download this from **[here](http://urlrewriter.net/)**