# IIS: How can I redirect requests for one page to another?

Tags: iis, redirect, request

I have written an app to replace a single page and need to redirect the requests for the old page to the new app.

In IIS, how would I redirect the request for

```
http://www.mysite.com/foo.aspx
```

to

```
http://www.mysite.com/bar/default.aspx
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

In your web.config do:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Foo_To_Bar" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^foo.aspx" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/bar/default.aspx" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

If you don't want to write the redirects by hand, there is a tool for URL Rewrite and Redirects: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module The installer says it is for 7.0 but it works with 8.5 as well.

Comment: does this work for just \foo.aspx or for any page called foo.aspx?

Answer (score -1):

What you need is URL rewriting.  There are a number of options.  Some are discussed in this question:

[IIS URL Rewriting vs URL Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90112/iis-url-rewriting-vs-url-routing)