# remove web folder from YII2 application on IIS

Tags: iis, yii2

I am trying to remove the web folder in the URL of my Yii2 web application hosted on windows server.
I want my application to be accessed at `http://example.com` instead of `http://example.com/web`
I have managed to enable pretty URLs using the code below.

```
    <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
```

how do I achieve this?

Comment: Create a website in IIS and set up the physical path pointing to the Web folder (path/to/app/web), and then place your webconfig file with your above content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually very easy on IIS when using Plesk.
Just change the document root to include the web folder.

[image: change the document root and include the web folder]

Answer (score 1):

These instructions are not for IIS but for Apache, you configure the Document root to the web folder.

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation#recommended-apache-configuration

Or maybe this answer will help guide you in the right direction.

[IIS document root in subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796085/iis-document-root-in-subfolder)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and direct solution for your requirement is to follow exactly the regarded [IIS configuration](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation#iis-configuration) in the official documentation.

In other words, you have to create a virtual host (it may be called *Sites* in IIS)  on your [iis](/questions/tagged/iis) that points to the `web` directory of your project and place `web.config` file with the code regarded in the documentation there.

**Hint**: you may need to edit your Windows `hosts` file to allow accessing this host locally.