# Extension-less URLs: Url Rerwrite or Routing?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, asp.net-routing

I would like to make my ASP.NET web page URLs without .aspx extensions. I can do it in two ways, use IIS7 URL Rewrite module or ASP.NET URL Routing. Which method to choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **ASP.NET Routing**. It's the most up-to-date and right way to do that, since **.NET 4.0**.

Read this [thorough article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/) regarding the subject written by the MSDN team (go to *Which Option Should You Use?*).

Routing keeps the request-resource resolution logic within your application, so it's very easy to add application-dependent logic when you need, and it eliminates the need to maintain synchronization between your application and a separate configuration resource.

Quote from the article mentioned above:

1. If you are developing a new ASP.NET Web application that uses either
   ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Dynamic Data technologies, use ASP.NET
   routing. Your application will benefit from native support for clean
   URLs, including generation of clean URLs for the links in your Web
   pages. Note that ASP.NET routing does not support standard Web Forms
   applications yet, although there are plans to support it in the
   future.
2. If you already have a legacy ASP.NET Web application and do
   not want to change it, use the URL Rewrite module. The URL Rewrite
   module lets you translate search engine-friendly URLs into a format
   that your application currently uses. Also, it lets you create
   redirect rules that can be used to redirect search engine crawlers
   to clean URLs.

Also read this thorough answer in SO: [IIS URL Rewriting vs URL Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90112/iis-url-rewriting-vs-url-routing/275043#275043)

Comment: While reading the article I found that in some cases I should use both technologies. For example I want to introduce "canonical URLs" rule for my app, as I understand from article it is not possible to do with ASP.NET Routing.

Comment: It's possible but requires some work. Canonical URLs, when set in IIS URL Rewriting, only change URLs per-request, but does not change the source HTML. So if your HTML (.cshtml, .aspx) contains upper-case URLs for example, your server will get 2 hits - one with the upper-case URL and the _301 Moved Permanently_ that the URL Rewriting Module points to. It's very ineffiecient.