# How to create profile links

Tags: c#, hyperlink, profile

I've been looking on how to create profile links like in Facebook "www.facebook.com/profile_name"?

Anyone knows how what is the term for that or links for that tutorial in ASP .Net C#?

EDIT:
What I'm trying to achieve here is to create a link for each member that could redirect to their profile page.
Here is an example of the link: www.mywebsite.com/**Member_Name**

I'm using ASP .Net Framework 3.5

Thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense at all. Are you talking about URLs? Like the url has a _profilename_ at the end and goes to the profile?

Comment: Sorry for that. I've been talking about the Rewrite_engine like what @Kevin have said.

Comment: You want to rewrite/change the urls right? I've written my answer assuming this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for mod_rewrite.

Search the web for apache mod_rewrite or friendly URLS to get up to speed on this topic.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine

Comment: Thanks! That's what I've been looking for. But do you know any tutorials regarding with this in ASP .Net c#?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you are talking about **Url rewriting or routing**.

I would suggest using *Asp.net Url routing*, which is supported Asp.net 3.5 SP1 onward.It's what `asp.net mvc` uses.

### Rewriting:

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/275043/368070) and this article on the difference between routing and rewriting. (This is to do with IIS/aspnet)

Url Rewrite is at the IIS level, for newer versions of IIS there is a URl rewrite module. [See this](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite). For older versions of IIS there is [this open source module](http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html).

### Routing:

Asp.net 3.5 SP1 onward supports routing, which is at the application code level. It can do what you want, something like `www.mysite.com/username` instead of `www.mysite.com/User.aspx?id=1234`. See this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37917/URL-rewriting-using-ASP-NET-routing) and [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202.aspx) for more info on this.

Comment: I've read the whole article but still I don't know where to start on how create the codes in creating a URL for each profile page.

Comment: Have you see the codeproject article? And the msdn article? What version of asp.net are you using?

Comment: I've seen both the codeproject and msdn article. I've tried the msdn article and I'm stuck at the `CustomRouteHandler` of the Global.asax.cs.

Comment: @ErnieAhsir How exactly are you stuck? Could you also put your requirement in your question, what is the page you have and what is the url you want? (Click `edit` in your question and add it there)