# WEB API URL Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want paths like this:

```
localhost:99/client/themes/plain/index.html?shop=mycoolshop
```

to appear as:

```
localhost:99/client/mycoolshop/index.html.
```

I wrote:

```
  routes.MapPageRoute(
            routeName: "Client",
            routeUrl: "client/{shopname}/{page}",
            physicalFile: "~/client/themes/plain/{page}?Shop={shopname}"
       );
```

But to no luck. When I type `localhost:99/client/mycoolshop/index.html` it says page not found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you asking for `index.html`?

Comment: My guess is that it's probably the '.' in index.html that's the problem. Can you try removing the extension from the file and URL and see what happens?

Comment: Are you using IIS or VS development server? When you click view in browser does it show localhost:99/Default.aspx?

Comment: How about using [Attribute Routing](http://attributerouting.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for URL Rewriting rather than WebAPI routing.  Take a look at this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90112/iis-url-rewriting-vs-url-routing)

Comment: Any links that tell how to do it with Web APIs...I am happy if the job gets done that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this setting in the system.web section of your web.config:

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

[Here's](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx) a more detailed explanation of how this works.