# htaccess page type redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've been searching for this forever but no solution, probably I'm not asking the right question but anyways..

I'm developing a new HTML website and going to replace it with a .ASP site which is already on the domain and I want to make sure when the site is live, everyone who goes to "site.com/contact.aspx" from Google will be 301 redirected to "site.com/contact.html"  (both for SEO and user experience purposes)

I need to have this on all pages. Page URLs and directories are ALL designed same as before, just page format is changing to HTML instead of .ASP

any .htaccess solutions for this?

( WE ARE MOVING AWAY FROM windows server to linux server)

thanks!

Comment: If you're using IIS (which I'm assuming you are) check our URL rewrite module. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90112/iis-url-rewriting-vs-url-routing

Comment: .htaccess doesn't work on IIS