# Get matching route from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do you retrieve the matching route for a URL (in string format)?

Basically something like...

```
Routes.GetMatchingRoute("http://mysite.com/foo/bar/1");
```

Without having a HttpContext.

Basically I would like to RedirectToAction using a referring URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* just return Redirect(url); instead of RedirectToAction();

I recall seeing someone ask that on SO before, but I can't find the question.

Edit: [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87221/asp-net-urlrewriting-and-constructing-page-links#87263) (note the edit by the OP), there was no answer there either.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear.  I also would like to pass the product model back into the redirect so it can repopulate form elements.  With Redirect you can't pass in the model.