# How to achieve dynamic page file names in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, filenames

I would like my website to create search-engine-optimized links for dynamic content (instead of locating data via the querystring). So:

```
mysite/SomeModifiableNname.aspx
```

instead of

```
mysite/DynamicContent.aspx?entryID=2345
```

.

Aside from a smart 404 handler that redirects requests, or a custom mime-type handler in IIS, is there a good solution for this in ASP.NET? 

*Keeping in mind that the page file name must be able to be changed at run-time.*

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262/asp-net-url-rewriting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's thoughts. With the information provided, I came across what I think is the solution I need:

In the Global.asax (or via an HttpModule), listen to the BeginRequest event and apply Context.Rewrite path there:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fullOrigionalpath = Request.Url.ToString();

    if (fullOrigionalpath.ToLower().Contains("/Games".ToLower()))
    {
        Context.RewritePath("Default.aspx?id=Games");
    }

}
```

And then, on the OnPreInit method of the page that will handle these requests, Rewrite path needs to be applied again so that PostBacks will work appropriately:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreInit(e);

    if (Request.QueryString["id"] == null)
        return;
    if (Request.QueryString["id"].ToLower().Equals("games"))
        Context.RewritePath("Games", "", "id=Games");
}
```

The key that makes this work better than a lot of URL-rewriting modules I came across is that the paths can be dynamic. That is, the created URLs can be data-driven.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a **HttpHandler**, as seen [here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeffrey.palermo/archive/2005/08/10/130532.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

this is a broad topic generally referred to as URL rewriting...

there are several ways to accomplish this. I would suggest looking into the IIS Rewrite Module.

You should probably also investigate the URL routing capabalities that were developed for MVC and are available in ASP.NET 3.51

UPDATE: I wish I knew more about your intentions. That last sentence confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in the past with UrlRewrite.Net.  There is also a built in facility for this in IIS7