# asp.net url rewriting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the url of one of my website

now currently the url looks like

```
www.sitenanme.com/details.aspx?videoid=XXXX&title=XXXXX
```

in which videoid and title comes from the codebehind file. now I have already used intellgencia url rewriter and I was able to write out the url where we hard code the url rewriting rule in web.config.

but in this case I want the url to become like

```
www.sitenanme.com/XXXXX(title)
```

Comment: Why not start with so many examples http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=asp.net+url+rewrite

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET URL Rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262/asp-net-url-rewriting)

Answer (score -1):

It is better to use MVC framework as it will save lot of your effort. However, if you still insist, please refer to example specified at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx

It does the same thing you are looking for.