# Url Mapping with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I'm creating a site, and i need to have my urls mapped . I want to avoid losing css during mapping. I want something like this..

```
http://www.vitagamer.net/Game.aspx?id=12
```

to

```
http://www.vitagamer.net/games/this-is-a-game-name/
```

now I've been thinking about the following algorithm..

1. receive the requested url..
2. break into parts, and search database for id associated with "this-is-a-game-name".
3. serve the `http://www.vitagamer.net/game.aspx?id=12` page

I've been looking on the web but i'm confused. How do I do the mapping?
how many ways are there?

is there a difference between rewriting and mapping?

---

Update

I also need to add hyperlinks to my pages that are shown like

```
http://www.vitagamer.net/games/gamename/
```

should I just do things with strings? or there's a more efficient way.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to read [Scott's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) about Url Rewritting

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to be on Asp.Net WebForms, I would suggest writing a HttpModule to catch the incoming requests and rewrite the URLs.

This is a duplicate question and I've found my suggested answer as the second one here: [ASP.NET URL Rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262/asp-net-url-rewriting?rq=1)

Comment: thnks for the reply, i'm reading about httpmodule..

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [`Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls`](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls/1.0.0-rc1) to easily use routing and get "friendly urls" or "extensionless urls" for ASP.Net Web Forms.

Here's a [primer from Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

IIS 7 has support for URL Rewrite, you can use IIS interface to manage URL(s):
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite