# How to implement Dynamic url rewriting in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-rewriting

I am using VS 2010. **I have created a website** in which I want to do url rewriting.

I have my all the files i.e. aspx file in admin and user folder.

In my application admin creates user and then if user types `www.domian.com\[username]\` in address bar then this should lead to user folder in my application

I want this type of url rewriting.

```
www.domain.com\\[Dynamic user]\login.aspx
```

Please suggest me if this can be achieved or not.

Any suggest would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it can be achieved and it was answered soooo many times that I'm voting to close this duplicate. Use google and do some research first before posting questions like this please. Don't create more work for people here who try to keep this site clean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET URL Rewriting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262/asp-net-url-rewriting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these articles, on how to use the UrlRoutingModule:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/77199/URL-Routing-with-ASP-NET-4-0

You can use controllers using the builtin Routes defined in [`System.Web.Routing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc490435.aspx) namespace, or also build your own `IRouteHandler : IHttpHandler` implementing class.

Basically the first place where they also are defined is in `Global.asax` or a derived `System.Web.HttpApplication` class, handling the `Application_Start` event.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("routeName",
    "{controller}/{action}", "~/Store/View.aspx");
}
```

Because `IRouteHandler` is wrapping `IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest`, the routing happens after the `Application_BeginRequest` event.

If you don't want to use `System.Web.Routing` namespace, using `UrlRoutingModule` and `IRouteHandler`, you have only `IHttpHandler`s like `StaticFileHandler` or `System.Web.Page` (the ASP.NET WebForm 'aspx' IHttpHandler).

At least you could create a simple ASP.NET WebHandler `.ashx` file (the simplest IHttpHandler).

So you said implementing...

It is notable that ASP.NET on older .NET Frameworks and IISs < 7 *can't rewrite anything*. Read about "IIS ASP.NET integrated pipeline".

Maybe the best answer for your question is probably 'not constructive', 'duplicate' or simply said *use search*, do *google* and say "asp.net url routing stackoverflow".

Comment: Give above link states that u can register the url which you want to route at Application Start.Application_Start event runs only once when the application first time runs.this is my problem i don't know what will be the username i.e. www.domain.com\cj first i need to check user cj is present in the database if yes show him the content inside the user folder